# Convert multidimensional array to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Is there a way to convert array into JSON like with the one below?

```
[[0, 68], [68, 68], [68, 205], [205, 205], [205, 286], [286, 286], [286, 347], [347, 347], [347, 482]]
```

I've tried `to_json` and `JSON.parse` but they do not work

Comment: expected output ... ?

Comment: I want to be able to loop with jQuery in the view

Comment: Is the answers are what you were looking for?

Comment: Define "they do not work". Without an example of what you tried, and an example of what you want we can't really help fix the problem you encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'json'

[[0, 68], [68, 68], [68, 205], [205, 205], [205, 286], [286, 286],
 [286, 347], [347, 347], [347, 482]].to_json
```

> => "[[0,68],[68,68],[68,205],[205,205],[205,286],[286,286],[286,347],[347,347],[347,482]]"

---

To deserialize this in JavaScript:

```
JSON.parse("[[0,68],[68,68],[68,205]]") // shortened for brevity
```

Comment: How do I loop this in jQuery?

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper The output of `JSON.parse` above is an array. You would "loop this" as you would any other array in JavaScript. If this doesn't answer your question, this is something that may need a separate SO question to answer.